# How to disable zoom and pan in a geopandas map created with explore()

Tags: leaflet, geopandas, folium

I've created a map with the explore() function in geopandas, but I want to fix the zoom level and disable mouse pan.

I've tried the following

```
merged1.explore(
     column="department", # make choropleth based on "department" column
     tooltip="decision_type", # show "decision_type" value in tooltip (on hover)
     popup=True, # show all values in popup (on click)
     tiles="CartoDB positron", # use "CartoDB positron" tiles
     cmap="Set1", # use "Set1" matplotlib colormap
     style_kwds=dict(color="black"), # use black outline
     zoom_control=False,
    )
```

`zoom_control=False` disables the zoom buttons, but I haven't been able to disable zoom on scroll or pan. I tried adding `dragging=False` and `scroll_wheel_zoom=False` to the arguments, but it didn't work.

How do I pass the arguments to the folium object and/or leafletjs to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look as **explore.py** within **geopandas** package,  you will find there is a constant list of *kwargs* that are passed to **folium** / **leaflet**

Extending this list with parameters defined in leaflet https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map that you want to use allows you to pass them from `explore()` call.

Below shows panning and zooming has been fully disabled.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import geopandas.explore

geopandas.explore._MAP_KWARGS += ["dragging", "scrollWheelZoom"]

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
world.loc[world["continent"].eq("Europe") & ~world["iso_a3"].isin(["RUS","-99"])].explore(
    # m=m,
    column="gdp_md_est",  # make choropleth based on "department" column
    tooltip="name",  # show "decision_type" value in tooltip (on hover)
    popup=True,  # show all values in popup (on click)
    tiles="CartoDB positron",  # use "CartoDB positron" tiles
    cmap="Set1",  # use "Set1" matplotlib colormap
    style_kwds=dict(color="black"),  # use black outline
    zoom_control=False,
    dragging=False,
    scrollWheelZoom=False
)
```